# what's the equivalent code based configuration to add log4j in spring MVC 3.0+

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am migrating my Spring MVC project to code based configuration, but not sure how to add a listener,

here's what in my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Here's my init class:

```
@Order(1)
public class Initializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { RootConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

I checked declaration of `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`, 
and tried to implement `onStartUp()` like below, but it complains `addListener` is not found.

```
@Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener log4jConfigListener = new org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener();
        container.addListener(log4jConfigListener);
        super.onStartup(container);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<listener>` element comes from web.xml, not from spring configuration.

What you are trying to achieve here is to programmaticaly add a Listener. This is a feature of [Servlet API 3.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). You will have to use servlet-api 3.0 to be able to do what you want.

For example Servlet api 3.0 is supported in Tomcat 6+ Jetty 8+ etc